# XeLaTeX - Invalid Font: -1

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I try to compile the following document using XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,draft]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Univers 65 Bold}  

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem Ipsum}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod 
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 

\end{document}
```

As a result I get the following (stripped) logfile:

```
Running `LaTeX' on `test' with ``xelatex  -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" test.tex''
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>

[...]

*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
* 
* Redefining document command \oldstylenums with arg. spec. 'm' on line 107.
*************************************************

[...]

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/Univers65Bold(0)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/Univers65Bold(0)/m/n' instead on input line 15.

[1] (./test.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.


** ERROR ** Invalid font: -1 (0)

Output file removed.
 )
Error 256 (driver return code) generating output;
file test.pdf may not be valid.
Transcript written on test.log.

LaTeX finished at Sun Jan 27 19:50:35
```

I have some trouble to interpret `Invalid font: -1`. Any thoughts on what might be causing the problem and, more importantly, how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. (Not pretty, some work, but solved the problem).

I had the font as Postscript Type 1. So I opened all font files with [Fontforge](http://fontforge.org) and saved them as OpenType. Afterwards I removed the Postscript fonts from my system and installed the OpenType version. Document compiled without problems.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have been searching for years... My font was a `ttf` format and for some reason `xelatex` compilation with `fontspec` package did not work. As a clarification, you should remove the bad extension font from the folder that LaTeX complains about in the error message you get. For me: `/home/myuser/.local/share/fonts`