# XeLaTeX prompting dvipdfmx:fatal error via Texmaker

Tags: xetex, miktex, texmaker, installing

I have recently set up my MiKTeX and Texmaker installation anew and have not been able to get any successful XeLaTeX compilation (via Texmaker) since then. This holds for the most basic examples. This file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\end{document}
```

compiles just fine with PDFLaTeX, but with XeLaTeX produces no pdf and the following log:

```
2022-10-11 11:34:55,942+0200 INFO  xelatex - this process (11536) started by texmaker in directory C:\Users\abc\Desktop\sample with command line: xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode sample.tex
2022-10-11 11:34:55,942+0200 INFO  xelatex - running on Windows 10.0.19044
2022-10-11 11:34:55,947+0200 INFO  xelatex - this is MiKTeX-XETEX 4.9.0 (0.999994) (MiKTeX 22.8.28)
2022-10-11 11:34:55,952+0200 INFO  xelatex - allowing known shell commands
2022-10-11 11:34:56,198+0200 INFO  xelatex.core - start process: miktex-dvipdfmx.exe -q -E -o sample.pdf
2022-10-11 11:34:56,726+0200 INFO  xelatex - this process (11536) finishes with exit code 0
```

While attempting to compile slightly more elaborate files that worked just fine before I reinstalled, I get the "dvipdfmx:fatal" prompt. Log file:

```
2022-10-11 11:45:03,525+0200 INFO  xelatex - this process (9960) started by texmaker in directory C:\Users\abc\Desktop\mock-q. 140 with command line: xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "q. 140.tex"
2022-10-11 11:45:03,525+0200 INFO  xelatex - running on Windows 10.0.19044
2022-10-11 11:45:03,530+0200 INFO  xelatex - this is MiKTeX-XETEX 4.9.0 (0.999994) (MiKTeX 22.8.28)
2022-10-11 11:45:03,534+0200 INFO  xelatex - allowing known shell commands
2022-10-11 11:45:06,912+0200 INFO  xelatex.core - start process: miktex-dvipdfmx.exe -q -E -o "q. 140.pdf"
2022-10-11 11:45:07,961+0200 FATAL xelatex.core - Invalid argument
2022-10-11 11:45:07,961+0200 FATAL xelatex.core - Function: fwrite
2022-10-11 11:45:07,961+0200 FATAL xelatex.core - Result: 22
2022-10-11 11:45:07,961+0200 FATAL xelatex.core - Data: <no data>
2022-10-11 11:45:07,961+0200 FATAL xelatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h:531
2022-10-11 11:45:07,961+0200 FATAL xelatex - Invalid argument
2022-10-11 11:45:07,961+0200 FATAL xelatex - Info: 
2022-10-11 11:45:07,962+0200 FATAL xelatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h
2022-10-11 11:45:07,962+0200 FATAL xelatex - Line: 531
2022-10-11 11:45:07,964+0200 INFO  xelatex - this process (9960) finishes with exit code 1
2022-10-11 11:45:07,966+0200 WARN  xelatex.core - still open: "q. 140.aux"
2022-10-11 11:45:07,966+0200 WARN  xelatex.core - still open: "q. 140.1"
2022-10-11 11:45:07,966+0200 WARN  xelatex.core - still open: C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts/tfm/public/cm\cmsy6.tfm
2022-10-11 11:45:07,966+0200 WARN  xelatex.core - still open: C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts/tfm/public/cm\cmsy8.tfm
2022-10-11 11:45:07,966+0200 WARN  xelatex.core - still open: C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts/tfm/public/cm\cmmi6.tfm
2022-10-11 11:45:07,967+0200 WARN  xelatex.core - still open: C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts/tfm/public/cm\cmmi8.tfm
2022-10-11 11:45:07,967+0200 WARN  xelatex.core - still open: C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts/tfm/public/cm\cmr6.tfm
2022-10-11 11:45:07,967+0200 WARN  xelatex.core - still open: C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts/tfm/public/cm\cmr8.tfm
2022-10-11 11:45:07,967+0200 WARN  xelatex.core - still open: "q. 140.tex"
2022-10-11 11:45:07,967+0200 WARN  xelatex.core - still open: "q. 140.log"
2022-10-11 11:45:07,967+0200 WARN  xelatex.core - still open: C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts/tfm/public/lm\ec-lmr10.tfm
2022-10-11 11:45:07,967+0200 WARN  xelatex.core - still open: C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts/tfm/jknappen/ec\ectt1000.tfm
2022-10-11 11:45:07,968+0200 WARN  xelatex.core - still open: C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts/tfm/public/latex-fonts\lasy6.tfm
```

Both files compile with no problem when running XeLaTeX via TeXnicCenter, so I assume this is some issue with the Texmaker installation. My uninformed guess would be that some leftovers from the previous installation interfere with the process. I have tried reinstalling it all, cleaning registers etc. but to no gain. Any hints you might have will be much appreciated: I have struggled with this for a few days and do not really see what else to try.

EDIT: I noticed that while a fresh TeXnicCenter installation compiles these files just fine, after some time - presumably after a few attempts to compile with Texmaker - XeLaTeX tool via TexnicCenter fails as well (with the same dvipdfmx:fatal prompt).

Perhaps [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617157/xelatex-produces-dvipdfmxfatal-invalid-font-1-22-error-only-on-certain-f) is somehow related (logs are similar), but I did not find any stray Type 1 fonts in my font directories, as was the issue there.

Comment: If you have a specific texmaker problem you should contact the texmaker support (there have been various questions about texmaker, but as it has no github or other public support forum it is unknown what do if it fails.).

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, this is definitely a sound idea.