# XeLaTeX w/ MiKTeX produces "dvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid font: -1 (4)" error

Tags: xetex, errors, miktex

I've tried following all these:

- [XeLaTeX - Invalid Font: -1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95599/xelatex-invalid-font-1)
- [XeLaTeX produces ‘dvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid font: -1 (22)’ error only on certain files and on certain computers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617157/xelatex-produces-dvipdfmxfatal-invalid-font-1-22-error-only-on-certain-f)
- [Using other fonts caused xdvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid font: -1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612718/using-other-fonts-caused-xdvipdfmxfatal-invalid-font-1)

And none of them helped.
I've tried to look for the type1 line in the font config files, and it wasn't even there.
And I've tried converting all the TrueType fonts to OpenType without success.
Also I've tried adding a line for truetype in the localfonts.conf file.

I've attached a screenshot and the document log file and XeLaTeX log file.
[image: Output screenshot]
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YmKcz2lh13WXVQO33qPZP0tQatZoiU8E/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zKYbuJRMzlKBndg88a1cdvszLaSJzQmm/view?usp=sharing

Edit:
Here's the font declarations inside the sty file:

```
\DeclareOption{fonts}{\setboolean{TULf@nts}{true}}

\DeclareOption{noheader}{\noTULheader}

\pagestyle{TUL}

\ProcessOptions

% aktivace pisem
\ifthenelse{\boolean{TULf@nts}}{
    \RequirePackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,BoldFont={* Bold}]{Inter}
    \setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,BoldFont={* Bold}]{Inter}
    \setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}
    \newfontfamily\TULmono[Ligatures=Contextual]{TUL Mono}
}{
    \newcommand\TULmono{\sffamily\bfseries}
}
```

And here's right on the first line of my document:

```
\documentclass[FM,BP,fonts]{tulthesis}
```

Edit2:
I've tried it on my old desktop w/ a fresh install of MiKTeX and it works flawlessly there. However even after a second reinstall of MiKTeX on my laptop it still spits out the same error and I don't know why.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: truetype fonts are not the problem, type 1 (Postscript) fonts will be but you have not shown an example